# How to retreive messages from the producer Side when artemis is down?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Explanation :
I have a consumer and producer  , I want to see that when I am pushing messages from the consumer side to the JMS(ARTEMIS) if the artemis is down 
then my messages are not accepted by artemis.

This means that when I turn on my artemis the messages are not there in the artemis queue bcz they are lost.

I want to know is there any configuration( like a buffer) which we can set in the context.xml of the consumer side so that we save the messages which are pushed , while the artemis is still getting back on track .

At the moment I have there parameters.

```
consumerWindowSize = 1024000000 bytes
producerWindowSize = 102400000 bytes
maxRetryInterval = 1000000 ms
setCallFailoverTimeout = 50000ms
```

Looking forward. Please help.

Comment: You can create master-slave cluster for ARTEMIS broker so if master will go down then slave will take care of your client messages until master will not wake up

Answer (score 3):

The Artemis JMS client does not provide any client side message buffering.  You would have to implement this yourself or use some other third party library to do that.

You could possibly run a local Artemis instance and use a bridge or network it to the normal remote such that the local broker continues to receive messages while the remote broker is down.

Comment: I see, so you mean to say that there is no way to use any configuration to put on the client side so we can have some buffer. INteresting .

Comment: so we might have to write a program where the local broker has a bridge with our real Artemis instance so when down and bought back up it can accept messages from the local instance.

Comment: What do you suggest for the bridge, like what type of bridge? If you can explain little more that would be really helpful.